# How to convert xs:date to xs:dateTime tibco

Tags: xpath, tibco

In my application, there is the following case:I have a "xs:date" and I need to convert it to "xs:dateTime". 
I tried `tib:format-dateTime("EEE MMM dd zzz 
yyyy",concat($Variable0/root/param,'00:00:00'))` but it doesn't work. How can write the xpath?

Answer (score 0):

You can use just **xsd:dateTime()** function : `xs:dateTime($Variable0/root/param)`

If param type is **xsd:date**, it will work and the output will be **xs:dateTime** type.

I'm using Tibco BW6.X and it works for me.